# Trigger CSS transform with jQuery more than once

Tags: jquery, css, transform

I have some code that successfully rotates a `div` how I'd like, however, it is only doing it once. I'm assuming this is because the function simply adds the CSS `transform` properties and once they are added, the browser (I'm using Chrome on Win7) doesn't care if they are added a second time. Is there a way to have the `div` rotate every time I click, rather than just once?

jQuery

```
$(function(){
    $('.hanging-div').on('click', function(){
        $(this).css({
            'transform':'rotate(-360deg)',
            '-ms-transform':'rotate(-360deg)',
            '-moz-transform':'rotate(-360deg)',
            '-o-transform':'rotate(-360deg)'
        });
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="hanging-div"><img src="http://placehold.it/65x350"></div>
```

CSS

```
.hanging-div {
    margin:0 auto;
    display:block;
    width:200px;
    padding:50px 0;
    transition:all 2s;
    -moz-transition:all 2s;
    -webkit-transition:all 2s;
    -o-transition:all 2s;
    transform-origin:50% 0%;
    -moz-transform-origin:50% 0%;
    -webkit-transform-origin:50% 0%;
    -ms-transform-origin:50% 0%;
    -o-transform-origin:50% 0%;
}
```

And here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MrP43/1/

**EDIT**

I've also tried removing the transform property afterwards, but it doesn't seem to have an effect.

```
$(function(){
    $('.hanging-div').on('click', function(){
        $(this).css({
            'transform':'rotate(-360deg)',
            '-ms-transform':'rotate(-360deg)',
            '-moz-transform':'rotate(-360deg)',
            '-o-transform':'rotate(-360deg)'
        }, function(){
                $(this).css({
                    'transform':'',
                    '-ms-transform':'',
                    '-moz-transform':'',
                    '-o-transform':''
                });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Does it work if (the 2nd time), you change the numbers (e.g. -360deg to -720deg)?

Comment: You could also try to remove the formatting and re-add it (if ofc this wouldn't cause the div to transform back first)

Comment: @GroundZero I've updated my post with some more details on removing the formatting. I'm still working on changing the 360 to 720.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I've figured it out thanks to @GroundZero. I simply made the degree of rotation a variable and subtracted 360 degrees from that variable for each click and now it works as expected. Now I wonder if this is the best way to go about doing this? It works, so I'm not complaining, but if anyone else has any solutions, I'd love to see them. Thanks!

```
$(function(){
    n = -360;
    $('.hanging-div').on('click', function(){
        $(this).css({
            'transform':'rotate('+n+'deg)',
            '-ms-transform':'rotate('+n+'deg)',
            '-moz-transform':'rotate('+n+'deg)',
            '-o-transform':'rotate('+n+'deg)'
        });
        n-=360;
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tuJjg/

Comment: Super weird behavior. Your approach works, however. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

Another possible approach would be to reset the transformation manually by reverse-transforming after the animation has finished:

```
$('.hanging-div').on('click', function(){
    $('.hanging-div').css({
        'transition':'all 0.45s ease-in-out 0s',
        'transform':'rotate(-360deg)' 
    });
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.hanging-div').css({
            'transition':'all 0s ease-in-out 0s',
            'transform':'rotate(0deg)'
        });
    }, 450); // transition duration goes here (in ms)
});
```

**Note:** it does not seem to work when using `$(this)`, not sure why... .